# How to correct the syntax error in the below query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN rule sod  ON ( 
    (
      xd.accou_id = sod.id 
      where  xd.item_type = 28
    ) 
    OR (
      pa.transaction_id = sod.id 
      AND pa.transaction_type = 28
    )
  )
```

my Error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where xd.item_type = 28 ) OR ( pa.transaction_id = sod.i' at line 147

Comment: hi, @nbk I have tried that too but some syntax error occurs.

Comment: @MeritonIsaac which errors occur?

Comment: That is clear, pleast my answer

Comment: I don't think this is a query-optimization question. Rather it's a query-syntax question.

Comment: I edited the question title to be more clear.

Comment: it was, I sorted the full table scan rows table .. remainings are doing good but this one was complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use WHERe, but you can use A CASE WHEN clause

Like

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    xd
        INNER JOIN
    pd ON xd.id = pd.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rule sod ON sod.id = CASE
        WHEN xd.item_type = 28 THEN xd.accou_id
        WHEN pa.transaction_type = 28 THEN pa.transaction_id
    END
```

[sample fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KCJE0itv)

Comment: @MeritonIssac please test see https://dbfiddle.uk/KCJE0itv

Comment: thank you, let me check :)

Comment: that was perfect